# Displaying "World From Space" projection pole-to-pole?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.0

The "Earth From Space" projection automatically displays the planet with a slight tilt to it. While I am sure this is more accurate, I need to display it un-tilted. I've tried adjusting projection specifications, but I can't seem to make it sit straight.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

There must be a way to show a planetary view from another angle.

[image: Mars]

Comment: Have you tried using ArcGlobe?

Comment: I tried using ArcScene in ArcPro, but it wouldn't rotate the globe as expected. I've never used ArcGlobe, I wasn't aware it existed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ArcGIS Pro go into the Coordinate Systems Properties.  Right-click on the "World from Space" projection and choose Copy and Modify.  Enter your own Latitude and Longitude of Center.